# Flow Forcing Use of SP Id in Update Item

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a Member List the has each member once, and a Status column.

I have a Training List. Each member may appear once or many times (depending on number of certs/quals each has), and also has the Status column.

My flow currently works. It updates the Member Training List Status based on any change the Member List.

The issue, I am being forced to use the SP Id in the 'Update item' action of my flow. In the action it shows 'required' even though I don't require it in my list for anything. Because the SP Id number don't match on both list, and because the Member appears multiple time on the Member Training List, the flow is updating the wrong line item.

So, the flow is working, just not 'exactly'.

I don't want to use the SP auto-generated Id. I have a UnqID in another column. I could use the 'UnqID' I've created (that matches exactly for each member on both lists), the hope is a change to the Member List will then Update item the 'Status' for the member on every line their name appears on the Member Training List.

Can I / How do I disengage the 'requirement' for the SP Id in the flow?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bypass the ID parameter for the fact that it helps SharePoint uniquely identify a list item in list (you can relate to concept of auto-incrementing primary key in SQL). The column is usually hidden you can enable it in view from view settings. As of now you need to pass ID. You can do this by using Get Item/Get-Items action and find the ID

Comment: What I can do now:

1. Update status with a Toggle in Power Apps. 
2. This action, along with a Patch function, updates the Status in the Member list.
3. I would like a flow to kick off (which already happens), that will update all items in the Member Training list that has the same 'UnqID' (a column I created) as the 'UnqID' of the item changed in the Member list. 

Currently the flow is only updating one item in the Member Training list, and that items belongs to the wrong Member.

Comment: you can use Get-Items with Filter query UniqID eq 'value', this will return all items with UniqID specified by you, then you can apply for loop on these items and update each of them you using ID column value of item.

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement,here is an example article about using Get items with filter query for your reference:

https://datasavvy.me/2017/07/16/updating-a-sharepoint-list-item-with-flow-when-you-dont-have-the-id/